# Forbidden error after urlencode

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem using `urlencode()` and I could not find a solution to it.
I am trying to get from my database an article that has a question mark at the end of the title:

```
new1/articles/details.php?name=test?
```

I use .htaccess to make the link friendly like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ articles/details.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and when I try to use `urlencode` I get the forbidden (403) error.
If I use `base64_encode()` it works but I want to have nice URL's.
This is from my access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2014:11:48:54 +0300] "GET /new1/articles/test+%3F HTTP/1.1" 403 306
```

and this from Apache error log:

```
[client 127.0.0.1:50434] AH00036: access to /new1/articles/test+? failed (filesystem path 'C:/wamp/www/new1/articles/test+?'), referer: http://localhost/new1/articles/
```

Comment: You need to urlencode only `name` field.

Comment: this is how i do it : <a href="<?php echo urlencode($row['name']);?>"

Comment: ok show me output of `var_dump( urlencode($row['name']) );`

Comment: string 'test+%3F' (length=8)

Comment: And do you see `http://example.com/new1/articles/test+%3F` in your browser?

Comment: In my experience, it is not possible to pass a `?` in any form through mod_rewrite.

Comment: yes i see it like that.